# Como descomponer un return?

Tags: javascript

Supongamos que de una función me llegó el siguiente return:

```
return {    
    x: 199,
    y: 200    
}
```

***Ojo: no puedo cambiar el return en si.***

¿Cómo puedo luego desde donde recibo el return modificarlo? O sea, por ejemplo:

Me llego `x:199` e `y:200` y quiero sumarle 20 ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: La pregunta no incluye lo buscado/investigado. Favor de seguir los lineamientos de [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que estas retornando es un [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object), por lo que puedes acceder a las propiedades `x` e `y` del objeto y alterarlas de la manera que desees.

```js
function someFunction(){
  return {
          x: 199,
          y: 200
         };
}

var obj = someFunction();
obj.x += 20;
obj.y += 20;
console.log(obj.x +","+obj.y);
```

Answer (score 3):

En tu pregunta haces referencia a

> Como descomponer un return?

Aunque luego en el texto preguntes algo ligeramente distinto, por completitud es adecuado hablar de [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment). Una opción introducida en ES6 para "desempaquetar" objetos de forma sencilla. En el ejemplo que pones si lo que interesara fuera realmente "descomponer" el objeto devuelto por el return podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
function foo() {
    return {
        x: 199,
        y: 200,
    }
}

let {x, y} = foo();
x += 20; 
y += 20;
console.log(x); // 219
console.log(y); // 220
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es crear una función que agregue funcionalidad.

Imagina una función de la siguiente manera

```
function Original(x,y)
{
  return {x,y}
}
```

Tú deseas agregar un mecanismo rápido para sumar a ambos valores, un cierto número, por lo tanto creas otra función que abstrae el proceso, primero copia la salida de la función Original y define un prototipo más cómodo

```
   function EnvolturaSumar(i)
    {
      this.x += i
      this.y += i
    }
```

Observa el ejemplo completo:

```js
function Original(x,y)
{
  return {x,y}
}

function Envoltura(x,y)
{
  if (this == window)
    throw new Error('debe utilizarse el operador new')
  Object.assign(this, Original(x,y)) 
}

function EnvolturaSumar(i)
{
  this.x += i
  this.y += i
}

Envoltura.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
   sumar: {value: EnvolturaSumar}
})

var x = new Envoltura(2,3)
console.log(x)
x.sumar(20)
console.log(x)
x.sumar(-10)
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function changeValorJson(){
  var a={};
  
          a.x= 1;
          a.y= 2;
         
         return a;
         
}
var valorJson = changeValorJson();
console.log(valorJson.x );
valorJson.x =valorJson.x + 100;

console.log(valorJson.x );
```

para acceder a un atributo de un objeto json debes usar el `.`, ejemplo

```
valorJson.x
```

Comment: He votado negativo, porque lo que retorna la función no es un JSON. JSON es un formato de texto para el intercambio de datos, las funciones js devuelven, en general, objetos.

Comment: @FranciscoPuga JSON tampoco es un formato de texto, JavaScript Object Notation, es un lenguaje como tal, tiene su propia gramática, la cual se describe [aquí](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.1). No veo por qué votar negativo por usar un termino equivocado cuando lo que afirmas también es equivocado.

Comment: Yo no voy a votar negativo, pero si que es verdad, que hay diferencias. Un JSON es texto con un determinado formato. Si lees la definición de `JSON#parse` dice algo así: `the parse function parses a JSON text and produces an ECMAScript value`

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo esta respuesta es de julio-24 y me di cuenta que no estaba en lo correcto

Comment: Perdona @x-rw no me fijé.